# How to make curves placed on surface random wavy?

Tags: geometry-nodes, bezier-curves

I have the following scene and geometry nodes:
[image: Geometry Nodes]

And my goal is to make these curves randomly wavy like this:

[image: Wavy curves]

I managed to do them wavy using Noise texture to Set Position Offset, but the problem there is that the root of the curves moving away and they are not as random as I want:

[image: Option]

How can I leave this curve wavy but leave the root in the center of the bulb? And can I make them more randomly wavy?

Edit: Here is .blend file: [image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Comment: You have to multiply the result of the _Scale_ node with the _Factor_ output of a _Spline Parameter_ node. The factor goes from 0 to 1 from beginning to end of a curve spline, so that the influence of the noise texture does not affect the curve at the beginning and the start position is not changed. Depending on the direction of your splines you might have to flip the direction of the factor with a _Color Ramp_, a _Map Range_ or maybe a _Float Curve_ node. Anything that can invert the 0 to 1 range if necessary, but even if not you can tweak the influence distribution.

Comment: @RickT thanks for the suggestion, updated the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GordonBrinkmann's comment in image ...

[image]
[image]

Comment: And for more randomness you could e.g. displace each sample by a random vector (the vector ID being set to the spline ID, so that the displace is the same across the entire spline; alternatively using a slower 4D noise texture and passing spline index to W dimension)